# CSS3 animation makes element with fixed position image stop working

Tags: html, css

In Google Chrome, when you have two elements, one that has a CSS3 animation and another with a background-image with a fixed position and an absolute positioned parent (important to keep that), the fixed property stops working when the animation is active.

Here is a JSFiddle, open in Chrome, scroll up and down to see the image be fixed, and then hover over the red square to see the fixed property break:

http://jsfiddle.net/keleturner/44mjq/

```
 <div class="animation">
</div>

<div class="background">
    <span></span>
</div>

.animation { display: block; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red; -webkit-transition: 1.8s -webkit-transform ease; }
.animation:hover { -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1); transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);}

.background { position: absolute; left:0; top: 300px; display: block; width: 100%; height: 500px; }
.background span { background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; background-image: url(http://image.jpg); width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the `body` element have the background? [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/44mjq/2/)

But to answer your question, it's rendering error due to the `body` increasing size due to the scale. To fix it add `-webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);` to either `.animation` or `.background`

But your setup is a silly one to have, it can be done in much better ways